Odoo : Get current model informations in the controller
I'm building a custom addon for Odoo which add a page on res.partner.form to display data from an external API.
Here is my code
views/my_view.xml
<data>
    <record id = "onglet_factu" model = "ir.ui.view">
        <field name = "name">La Factu</field>
        <field name = "model">res.partner</field>
        <field name = "inherit_id" ref = "base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name = "arch" type = "xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='internal_notes']" position='after'>
                <page string='Onglet API'>
                    <h2>Fake API</h2>
                    <field name="data" widget="my_widget"/>
                </page>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

then I add the new field in my model
from odoo import models, fields
models/api.py
class Api(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    data = fields.Char()

I use a javascript class to make the API call via a controller and display in a Qweb template
static/src/js/api_component.js
export class MyApiField extends Component {
    setup() {
        super.setup();
        onWillStart(async () => {
            var id = this.env.model.root.data.id
            fetch('/napsis_factu/test?id='+id)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.state.data  = {
                        data1 : data['data1'],
                        data2: data['data2']
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.message);
                });
        })

    }

}

MyApiField.template = "addon.template";
MyApiField.props = {
    ...standardFieldProps,
};
MyApiField.supportedTypes = ["char"];

export const apiField = { component: MyApiField };
registry.category("fields").add("my_text_field", apiField);

And here is the controller call in the javascript class :
controllers/api_call.py
@http.route('/myaddon/api-call', auth='user', csrf=False )
  def calling(self, **kwargs):
    theId = # How to get the ID of the res partner object I'm on ??
    payload = {   "Ctxt": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "ID": theId,
                    }
    req = urllib.request.Request(url='https://myapi', headers={
        "Content-Type":"application/json"}, data = json.dumps(payload).encode())
    reply = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('UTF-8'))
    if reply.get("error"):
     print('Alert!!')
     raise Exception(reply["error"])
    return json.dumps(reply) 

I'm wondering if it would be possible to get, within the controller, the informations of the current model. Now I pass this via my javascript call but would it be possible to get the ID of the res.parner.form.view I'm on ? Do you know how to do it ?
Thanks !

What Odoo version?

I'm on Odoo version 16

You can use odoo.http.request and the partner id passed throw the  kwargs parameter to get the partner record
Example:
partner_id = int(kwargs.get('id', 0))
partner = request.env['res.partner'].browse(partner_id)

You can find an example in website_profile module

Thank you ! But I can't get the partner_Id of the res.partner.form I'm on directly in the controller ? I must pass it in the kwargs ?

Yes, like you did in fetch

Thanks a lot for your help. Last question : is it better to dit on javascript size with my fetch or dircetly in the controller ?

Usually you have to import odoo.http.request and can use this like:
# other imports
from odoo.http import request

class MyController:

    @http.route('/myaddon/api-call', auth='user', csrf=False )
    def calling(self, **kwargs):
        user_id = request.env.user.id
        partner_id = request.env.user.partner_id.id


Thanks for your answer. This gives you the id of the company of the loggin user. I would like to have the id of the company's page I'm on. Let's say I'm on the Azure Interior res.partner form view, I would like to have it's Id. Sorry if it's not clear...

What do you mean by page? I have no idea what your controller is used for. How is it called?

Precisely, my controler is used for an external API calling. By page,I mean res.partner.form (indeed it's not the correct word) . I added a custom page on this form that display data from this external API through a field widget. So I call my controller from a javascript class. I pass the ID through this javascript call but I would prefer the information directly within the controller

Do we speak about two Odoos here? Or why do you need an extra controller for your widget? What about using a "plain" rpc call in javascript (OWL and Old Framework example)?

I tried a rpc call for the external API but I get a CORS error so I prefered to make the API call via python.
